# What is the most effective to sync all the data present in my server with the database in my ipad application?

Tags: ios, sql-server, xml, ipad, sqlite

I have a lot of data present in the database present in my webserver. Each time I starts the ipad application after downloadiding, I want all these data to be copied into the sqlite database present in my application. Then using this data, the application should work.

We are now using xml's and sometimes on 3g it takes about 20minutes which is completely unacceptable. After the 1st time it syncs using time log and all. And it works without any problem.

Is there any other way I could get all the data and make it populated into my sqlite db?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a large database it might be worth doingin the background. And even better if it was just over wifi (otherwise you'll be eating up your users data)

What I usually do is have a local copy of the database shipping with the app, so the user can use that, and update it in the background. It might be worth creating some pages where you just present the updated content, download that, then update your database accordingly. Rather than downloading everything all the time.
This would depend entirely on your implementation however.

Comment: No, The content is not something that is to be preloaded. Data gets added up in the server all the time. First time when application is downloaded, all these are to be downloaded together. After that when we sync each time, it just fetches the data after the first download. So it will be fine.

Comment: In that case there is no other way to transfer data, the only way to make it quicker is to make it smaller. Maybe switch to JSON as it is more lightweight than XML

Answer (score -1):

On initial app launch you could download just enough data to make the app functional. Then download the rest of the data in the background.

This is a common strategy used by Sync Frameworks and works pretty well. I have personally tried with with synchronizing more than a thousand objects using OpenMobster's sync service.

Now what data to download initially is to be decided by the requirements of the App

Thanks